# JSON Assoc Array to Variables?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON associate array

```
[{"Test":"5:00pm"},{"Testing2":"4:30 pm"}]
```

and I want to make it so that it becomes an array where

```
{
  theatre = Test
  time = 5:00pm
},
{
  theatre = Testing2
  time = 4:30 pm
}
```

But I can't figure out how to take a key name and make it a value...

Any help? I was looking at `Object.keys` but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array with object values. You'd need to loop over them:

```
var oldArray = [{"Test":"5:00pm"},{"Testing2":"4:30 pm"}];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys(oldArray[i]);

    newArray.push({
        theatre: keys[0],
        time: oldArray[i][keys[0]]
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FNAtw/

This will give you an array stored in `newArray` with two elements. The first element is an object with kvps `theatre: 'Test'` and `time: '5:00pm'`. The second element is an object with kvps `theatre: 'Testing2'` and `time: '4:30pm'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
var json = '[{"Test":"5:00pm"},{"Testing2":"4:30 pm"}]';
var betterJson = json.replace('{"', '{"theatre":"').replace('":"','",time:"');
```

If the JSON is always as simple as above, then this should work. But it's brittle...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JS object, you could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). That will work in the latest browsers.

You can also loop each item and just save the 1st item.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
var str = [{"Test":"5:00pm"},{"Testing2":"4:30 pm"}];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    foreach (var key in str[i]) {
        obj.theatre = key;
        obj.time = str[i][key];
    }
    result.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit clunky, BUT should work cross-browser.

```
var js = [{"Test":"5:00pm"},{"Testing2":"4:30 pm"}]
var newJSON = []
for(var i = 0; i< js.length; i++) {
    for( var key in js[i]) {
        if(js[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var tmpJS= {};
            tmpJS['theater'] =  key;
            tmpJS['time'] = js[i][key];
            newJSON.push(tmpJS);
        }
    }
}
```